# docker - failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1) no space left on device

Tags: arch-linux, docker, symlink, disk-usage

I am on **Manjaro**.

I keep getting:

```
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0: no space left on device
```

while [downloading](https://hub.docker.com/r/kdeneon/all):

```
docker pull kdeneon/all
```

This is the output of `df -H`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             2.6G     0  2.6G   0% /dev
run             2.6G  930k  2.6G   1% /run
/dev/dm-0        16G   11G  4.8G  69% /
tmpfs           2.6G   39M  2.6G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.6G     0  2.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2.6G   48M  2.6G   2% /tmp
/dev/dm-1        18G  631M   17G   4% /home
tmpfs           514M  4.1k  514M   1% /run/user/1000
```

I have even symlinked the images directory from `/var/lib/docker/image` to `/home/newbie/docker/image`. Since `/home` has only `4%` usage.

```
ls -l /var/lib/docker/image
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Mar  9 07:32 image -> /home/newbie/docker/image/
```

This has no effect.

What else can I do ? Why is this happening ?

Comment: According to https://hub.docker.com/r/kdeneon/all/tags the compressed size of the image is 2.15GB, so it is not too surprising that holding both a compressed and an uncompressed copy exceeds the 4.8GB. The output of your `ls` command is unexpected, I would expect it to say `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Mar  9 07:32 /var/lib/docker/image -> /home/newbie/docker/image/` which makes me think you have linked /var/lib/docker/image/image to /home/newbie/docker/image.

Comment: @icarus Yeah what is the problem ? I have linked `/var/lib/docker/image/image` to `/home/newbie/docker/image`. I don't understand your point. Are you saying that I have not linked correctly ? If so what is the correct linkage ?

Comment: You want `/var/lib/docker/image` to be linked, not `/var/lib/docker/image/image`. If I was doing it I would make `/var/lib/docker` be the symlink.

Comment: @icarus I had to move the docker data to another partition. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to solve this problem is to move the docker data directory to another location where there is sufficient space. In my case this was my home partition.

To do that I had to create a `daemon.json` file in `/etc/docker` and add the following lines to it:

```
{
    "data-root": "/home/newbie/docker_data"
}
```

Then restart the docker service, if you are suing systemd this should be:

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error on a Mac computer without Docker Desktop. And moving the docker data directory did not work for me.

This is what worked for me using minikube.

```
minikube stop && minikube delete // this is required
minikube start --memory=16384 --cpus=8 --disk-size='80000mb'
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Then try your `docker pull...` again.

Comment: Did you change memory and/or disk when starting again or was it the same as before `delete`?